# How to store user settings completely internally in an exe with C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, windows, exe

this is more of a question on how and if, then to actually fix a problem.

> How can you store user settings completely internally in an exe with C/C++?

Is this even possible, and if so how can it be done? I'm mostly just curious as I can't really think of a way, and to me some some applications seem to do that.

*Note: I already know about the methods such as spawning a child process, using files, the cloud or registry, I was just wondering if you could actually save the settings internally.*

Comment: Are you unable to write files? Is this only while running, or, persistence after shutdown? If you need both, you could do a web query, which data is stored externally. (Think clouds)

Comment: 'some some applications seem to do that' - please name one.

Comment: Have you considered using the registry for that? Maybe this is the place those "magic" applications store their settings.

Comment: @MartinJames, I said, seems, it looks like they save settings internally, or it may be some obscure registry entry or something, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @monkey, I know about that, but I was wondering if you could truly do it internally, with persiticance after shutdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can albeit with a roundabout way.
But you would have to worry about the repercussions of modifying an executable which may prevent it from ever being executed again.

for example, if you make a program with a simple

```
int main()
{
   std::cout<<"This is some text to display"<<std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

you'll see in the executable (if you open in notepad and search) that the string "This is some text to display" is plaintext inside of the binary file.

The theory I have is, you could use a stringstream object with an insertion operator into a variable, then get the value.

So you would load the executable, and a thread or console app after, to search for the values in the executable that are provided in plain text and over write them. However, I don't know if they're size delimited or something of the sort. So there's a good chance doing so would break your program.

Again, this is a potential work around, I can't see why you'd wish to do something like this though. Not to mention you could potentially break the entire executeable.

Comment: Thanks, interesting thought, i'll be sure to try it. as for why, its for fun, i was curious.

Comment: I like your thinking, it keeps me thinking.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a way since an executable can't modify itself while running.  You can spawn another process that will modify the original executable after it closes, but that's just silly.

There's an interesting discussion on this exact topic and how people tend to store user settings here:

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/83391-saving-settings-data-executable-itself-permenent-basis.html

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this could be to pack the real executable and the configuration file in a self-extracting compressed file (zip or alike). The self-extracting executable would unpack to a temporary directory and execute the program from there. The program can create/modify config files and pack them again into the self extracting file. There would be a couple of things to deal with, like how to locate what the location of the self-extracting compressed file is to be able to repack...

Comment: That's a nice way to do. Not quite what I had in mind, but nice.

Comment: Another way could be creating a static object with the configuration in the code (assuming that all objects have fixed size) and then from the program read the executable, locate the symbol and overwrite it...